# Postgres production server: more rollbacks than commits?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I'm studying a little Postgres 9.3 stats, and I've observed that in my servers, this simple query:

```
select sum(xact_commit) as commits,sum(xact_rollback) as rollbacks from pg_stat_database;
```

I have curiosity to know the cause why it returns always more rollbacks than commits.

This is also true, for incremental values:

```
postgres=# select sum(xact_commit),sum(xact_rollback) from pg_stat_database;

     sum     |    sum    

------------+-----------

 1045889770 | 148206853

postgres=# select sum(xact_commit),sum(xact_rollback) from pg_stat_database;

    sum     |    sum    

------------+-----------

 1045890403 | 14820767

commits = 1045890403-1045889770 = 633
rollbacks = 148207673-148206853 = 820
```

I expect to have more commits  than rollbacks, in normal conditions.
Any idea?

Comment: Do you have any errors in logs in time?

Comment: I have some errors, but most SQL succeed (otherwise my customers would complain).  Probably I misunderstanding the stats.

Comment: a successful query does not mean the whole transaction will be committed. however a unsuccessful query means that the transaction is rolled back (if you don't handle that error in plpgsql) . Moreover you can rollback transactions in your application. I suggest you to test that numbers with a clean postgresql installation. run queries and check counts, rollback some transactions and check counts etc.